# How to shuffle a Numpy array file when it is too large for the memory to load?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to split this `60GB` Numpy array file and shuffle it for my model training, but I couldn't load it with just np.load since my computer ran out of memory and restarted itself when I tried it.

Is there a convenient way to load such a big file and shuffle it with limited memory?